# Washing machine sound coming from top springs

Tags: washing-machine, sounds

My 8-years-old washing machine (Siemens WM14E442BY) forced me to replace its worn shock absorbers as well as all bearings. Once done, the washing machine finally stopped the sounds which were generated during spin cycle.

However, new sounds were introduced during slow spinning. I have managed to figure out the reason - the top springs on whose the drum is hanging. If I move the drum by hands, in certain angles the springs rub against the metal pillar making a vibrating metal sounds, which - amplified by the machine body - are quite loud and sound like the drum is hitting the machine's metal body.

I have extensively greased the connection between springs and the metal pillar. However, after a few washing cycles it is back.

Does anybody solved such a problem? Not really sure what is wrong. The only idea I get is that the metal pillar is worn out and even the grease does not prevent it to rub against the springs. I.e. the spring does slide to sides without friction, and once the friction is overcame it behaves like a guitar spring.

[image: The pillar joins with springs]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turning the springs around did the trick, after about 10 washing cycles, no metal sound is coming out of the machine.

I.e. the problem was the wear on spring hooks.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to slip a shim of some softer metal (Al, Cu, or brass) under the hook. You could form a groove in the shim before placing it. Maybe the friction would be greater and the hook would not move.

Another approach is to completely immobilize the spring on the support. That would be a clamp of some kind. The simplest would be to screw a plate on so that it immobilizes the top of the hook on the spring. If the spring is moving relative to the support I think it will wear through the spring or the support or both.

Is it slipping by 'swinging' in the plane of the hook or by shifting back and forth perpendicular to the plane of the hook?

Comment: If you use a plate to clamp, it could have a slot (or maybe just a groove) in it into which the hook would fit so that it wold not move perpendicular to the plane of the hook. The easiest thing one imagines is the plate would be secured by self tapping or self drilling  screws into the crossbar, but you could possibly have it fit into the opening and then clamped on the other end.

Comment: The left/right moves of the drum are the ones which force the springs to "rotate" left/right around the plane, parallel to the metal support. See the attached picture I have added.

My first fix attempt was to grease the space between support's plane and the springs, but that did not fix anything. Based on the current design, it seems the springs were supposed to be free to move in the support's plane. To me it seems the replacement shock absorbers work worse than the original.

Comment: The new springs might be stiffer than the original ones. In any case the contact is steel on steel and this cannot have been intended to have relative movement because it would wear and squeak. I would try to immobilize the hook on the support.

Comment: I have disassembled the springs, and took a look on the support bar as well as spring hooks. Both are quite worn. The support planes are smooth, polished. However, the springs have visible wear and by hand I could feel the edges on the spring hooks. So I turned them around, because the other hook - hooked into plastic drum - was nice unweared. Let´s see what happens. If this does not help, I will immobilise the springs. Thanks buddy for help!